# Python and CSV: Output everything to one line

Tags: python, csv

So I have written a program that inserts tuples into a .csv file. This is the code:

```
with open('data.csv','a') as out:

        csv_out=csv.writer(out)
        #csv_out.writerow(['Restaurant Name','Change'])
        for x, y in zip(arrayForInitialSpots, arrayForChosenSpots):
            csv_out.writerow(x+y)
```

And it works fine because it outputs:

```
Café A,0,Café B,0
Restaurant A,0,Restaurant B,0
Restaurant C,0,Restaurant D,0
E's Place,0,F's Restaurant,0
```

But what I want is to write the above in one single line, so:

```
Café A,0,Café B,0,Restaurant A,0,Restaurant B,0,Restaurant C,0,Restaurant D,0,E's Place,0,F's Restaurant,0
```

How do I do this? I've tried to .format() the r\n\ character but it still doesn't do what I want it to do. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of the CSV module is to 
get results out in a tabular way. If you don't want that 
just skip the `csv` module altogether, and output with `write` directly to a file:

```
with open('data.csv','a') as out:
     starting = True
     for x, y in zip(arrayForInitialSpots, arrayForChosenSpots):
          for item in (x + y):
              if not starting:
                 out.write(", ")
                 starting = False              
              out.write(item + ", ")
```

--
However, CSV can do other nice things, like correctly escaping quotes
in the textual data itself. If you will need these features, then just
squash all your data to a single list before performing the output:

```
data = []
for x, y in zip(arrayForInitialSpots, arrayForChosenSpots):
    data.extend(x + y)
with open('data.csv','a') as out:
     csv.writer(out).writerow(data)
```

**NB**: from your sample output data and snippets in the question, I can't tell if you want the value in "y" to be separated by a comma from the value in "a" or not - just modify the `data.append` expression (possibly using two `data.append` calls) to fit your needs.

**update**: changed to properly acomodate O.P. data as detailed in the comments. (i.e. use "extend" rather than "append" in the second snippet, and equivalent changes in the first)

Comment: Hey, So I tried the above, but now my data comes out in a pretty ugly manner. I think it's because of the nature of tuples, but anyway, here's a snippet: "(u""Restaurant A"", 0, u""Restaurant B"", 0)","(u'Restaurant C', 0, u'Restaurant C', 0)","(u""Restaurant D"", 0, u""Restaurant D"", 0)","(u""Restaurant E"", 0, u""Restaurant E"", 0)","(u'Restaurant F', 0, u'Restaurant F', 0)","(u'Restaurant G', 0, u'Restaurant G', 0)","(u'Restaurant H', 0, u'Restaurant H', 0)","(u'Restaurant I', 0, u'Restaurant I', 0)" Suggestions?

Comment: Sorry - inddeed - both your `x` and `y` are 2-tuples - my example as it is put those together in a 4-tuple, which then counts as a single data element in both snippets. This can be fixed by using `data.extend` instead of `data.append`. (I will fix it above)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data.csv','a') as out:
     out.write(', '.join(x+y for x, y in zip(arrayForInitialSpots, arrayForChosenSpots)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `lineterminator` argument to the writer class

```
import sys
import csv

W = csv.writer(sys.stdout, lineterminator=",")
W.writerow(["a", "b", "c"])
W.writerow(["d", "e", "f"])
```

This has one disadvantage, in that the output stream terminates with a ',', but otherwise works just like you might wish.